# Unable to insert data using mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, workbench

I'm trying to insert some data into my database using a form. After filling the form i am taking data using method="POST". I have no syntax errors, although i can't insert the data from my form to my database.

Here is some code of php:

```
<?php

    // Connects to your Database
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "134711Kk", "eam3");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //This is the directory where images will be saved
    $target = "dokupload/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
    echo $target;
    echo "<br>";

    $name=$_POST['nameMember'];
    $bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];


    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Connection Failed".mysql_error());     
    }

    echo "$name" . " " . "$bandMember" . "<br/>";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Grammateia(id, idruma, tmhma) VALUES ('1', '$name', '$bandMember');";   

    $some = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    $request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eam3.Grammateia;", $con);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request))
    {   
        extract($row);
        echo "$id" . " " . "$idruma" . " " . "$tmhma" . "<br/>";
    }


    .
    .
    .

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I managed to pass some data in my database through mysql workbench, but not with php code. Can you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now change your password. And see about the deprecation of PHP's mysql_ API, sql injection and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mysqli instead of mysql as it is deprecated.

Write `mysqli_query($con,$sql)` not `mysqli_query($sql,$con);`

Try below code

```
<?php

    // Connects to your Database
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "134711Kk", "eam3");

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    //This is the directory where images will be saved
    $target = "dokupload/";
    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
    echo $target;
    echo "<br>";

    $name=$_POST['nameMember'];
    $bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];


    if(!$con)
    {
        die("Connection Failed".mysqli_error());     
    }

    echo "$name" . " " . "$bandMember" . "<br/>";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Grammateia(id, idruma, tmhma) VALUES ('1', '$name', '$bandMember');";   

    $some = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $request = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM eam3.Grammateia");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($request))
    {   
        extract($row);
        echo "$id" . " " . "$idruma" . " " . "$tmhma" . "<br/>";
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the ';' from you query.

This should be your best resource http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Why point to a deprecated API? Although, to be fair, I suppose the link does at least say taht it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Connects to your Database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "134711Kk", "eam3");

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "dokupload/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);
echo $target;
echo "<br>";

$name=$_POST['nameMember'];
$bandMember=$_POST['bandMember'];


if(!$con)
{
    die("Connection Failed".mysql_error());     
}

echo "$name" . " " . "$bandMember" . "<br/>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO Grammateia(id, idruma, tmhma) VALUES ('1', '$name', '$bandMember')";   

$some = mysql_query($sql, $con);

$request = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM eam3.Grammateia;", $con);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($request))
{   
    extract($row);
    echo "$id" . " " . "$idruma" . " " . "$tmhma" . "<br/>";
}

.
.
.

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You sample isn't the recommend approach for inserting data (you should really be using `mysqli->prepare` to be safe). But, to fix what you have here:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Grammateia(id, idruma, tmhma) VALUES ('1', '" . $name . "', '" . $bandMember . "');";
```